# How to embed Piccolo2D canvas inside JavaFX?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8, piccolo

How to embed `Piccolo2D` canvas inside `JavaFX`?

I thought it should work via [SwingNode](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html), since `Piccolo` has `Swing` control named [PCanvas](http://www.piccolo2d.org/doc/piccolo2d.java/release-1.3/core/apidocs/edu/umd/cs/piccolo/PCanvas.html).

This approach works with Swing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        PPath ellipse = PPath.createEllipse(100,100,400,200);

        PCanvas canvas = new PCanvas();
        canvas.getLayer().addChild(ellipse);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setTitle("PCanvas_Try01");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

but this doesn't work with `JavaFX`:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        PPath ellipse = PPath.createEllipse(100, 100, 400, 200);

        PCanvas canvas = new PCanvas();
        canvas.getLayer().addChild(ellipse);

        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        swingNode.setContent(canvas);

        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group);

        stage.setTitle("PCanvas_Try02");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some issues with `Group`. The following seems to work:

```
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.nodes.PPath;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.PCanvas;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DemoPiccoloFx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        PPath ellipse = PPath.createEllipse(100, 100, 400, 200);

        PCanvas canvas = new PCanvas();
        canvas.getLayer().addChild(ellipse);

        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        swingNode.setContent(canvas);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 500, 300));
        stage.setTitle("PCanvas_Try02");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using PSwingCanvas? It's purpose looks reverse!

Comment: @SuzanCioc Yes, correct, no need in this case, it works fine with `PCanvas`. But if you're adding `PSwing` nodes then there should be `PSwingCanvas`. I updated the answer to remove it.